# SQL Server: INSERT INTO SELECT MAX

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to insert multi rows from another table.  The problem is that I want to get the `Max + 1` before I insert.  Note that I know I should use Identify etc... However, I have this complex scenario of offline database synchronization across nodes...

```
INSERT INTO Purchase_Deliveries_Items    
  (ID,Item_ID)
SELECT 
    (SELECT 
        MAX(ID)+1  -- same MAX ID for all (the problem)
    FROM 
        Purchase_Deliveries_Items), 
    Item_ID,
FROM 
    Purchase_Orders_Items
WHERE 
    PurchaseOrder_ID = 1
```

Comment: *"-- same MAX ID for all "* - Is that the problem description or the desired outcome?

Comment: thats the problem, i want to get the unique max(id) per row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a newid based on the max existing id with the help of [ROW_NUMBER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)

```
INSERT INTO Purchase_Deliveries_Items (
    ID,
    Item_ID
)
SELECT  
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        ORDER BY
            Item_ID
    ) + (SELECT MAX(ID)
            FROM Purchase_Deliveries_Items) newID,
    Item_ID,
FROM Purchase_Orders_Items
WHERE 
    PurchaseOrder_ID = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want to do a kind of sequence, use a ROW_NUMBER:

```
INSERT INTO Purchase_Deliveries_Items    
   (ID,Item_ID)
        SELECT  (
                    SELECT MAX(ID)  -- same MAX ID for all 
                    FROM Purchase_Deliveries_Items 

                ) + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY any_column), 
                Item_ID,
        FROM Purchase_Orders_Items
        WHERE PurchaseOrder_ID = 1
```